# Slicing (seperating) segments out of audiofiles (arrays) and deleting them

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-itertools, librosa

I want to slice specific segments out of long audiofiles (10min.+) and save them separetly. So far it works fine, but i want to delete those segments from the array and shorten the array.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

start = 2
stop = 4
index = list(range(start, stop+1))
print(index)

b = np.array(list(itertools.compress(b, [i not in index for i in range(len(b))])))
print(b)
```

That was my approach, but it doesn't work in the real script with much bigger numbers. I use librosa to load and save the audiofiles but i haven't found a useful command for my problem.

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use np slicing and concatenation of arrays as:

np.concatenate([b[0:start],b[stop:len(b)]])

Hope this helps